# PHP Sessions: Generate a variable and save it for session

Tags: session, session-variables, session-cookies, php

I am totally new to php sessions. I am not able to get a simple task done. 
This is what I am trying to do:

- A visitor of my website gets shown a random image

well this part works so far. But everytime the user goes on to another page (I have this random image shown on all pages) the script generates a new random image to be shown.

What I want to do now is:

- Save the random image variable to a session so he will see the same image on each page he visits while he has the session saved.

Here is my working code to get a random image without saving it into sessions. If anybody could help me with how the code should look like so it works with sessions would be awesome. Remember: I am a total newby when it comes to sessions.

As you can see I need the variable $img to be stored into a session after it got generated. And the script only to strt again on a new site visit if a user hasnt stored the $img variable in his session.

```
<?php
function getImagesFromDir($path) {
$images = array();
if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
    while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
        // checks for gif, jpg, png
        if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
            $images[] = $img_file;
        }
    }
    closedir($img_dir);
}
return $images;
}

function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 ); // php 4.2+ not needed
$num = array_rand($ar);
return $ar[$num];
}


$root = '';
// use if specifying path from root
//$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$path = 'images/';


// Obtain list of images from directory 
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);
$img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
?> 

<img src="/<?php echo $path . $img ?>" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add this at the top of every page to get your image:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['UserImg'])){
   $img = $_SESSION['UserImg'];
}
else {
    $img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
    $_SESSION['UserImg'] = $img;
}
```

This should work out!

Comment: Hi. Thanks. This seems to work. But the problem is the script is generating the $img on each page as you already figured out. What I now need is a code that the function $img = getRandomFromArray($imgList); is only running if the user has no variable stored in his session. how to do that?

Comment: I guess I got it.
I did this:


<?php 
session_start();
?>

if(isset($_SESSION['UserImg'])){
   $img = $_SESSION['UserImg'];
}
else {
$img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
}

$_SESSION['UserImg'] = $img;
?>

Comment: Yes, that should work out! Add `$_SESSION['UserImg'] = $img;` in the else block itself. Otherwise you're already having the session variable.

Comment: thanks this works. of course the     $_SESSION['UserImg'] = $img; needs to be removed then outside the else so it is only called once

Answer (score 0):

on top of each page call:

```
session_start();
```

To safe variable in session for example:

```
$_SESSION['imageid'] = $ID
```

To get the variable back:

```
$imageid = $_SESSION['imageid']
```